# CLion - can't run a program on apple m1

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I ran clion a month ago and it worked perfectly. Now when I run a program I get:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/a/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion-ARM/ch-0/203.7717.62/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 127
```

Also, on clion startup, the cmake tool window shows me an error:

```
CMake Warning at /Users/a/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-1/211.7142.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/Platform/Darwin-Initialize.cmake:303 (message):
  Ignoring CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT value:

   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk

  because the directory does not exist.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/a/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-1/211.7142.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInitialize.cmake:21 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /Users/a/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-1/211.7142.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/a/CLionProjects/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_e3f61/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f61.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f61.dir/build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f61.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc   -arch arm64 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f61.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/a/CLionProjects/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_e3f61
    "/Users/a/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-1/211.7142.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f61.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc  -arch arm64 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f61.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_e3f61 
    ld: library not found for -lSystem
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_e3f61] Error 1
    make: *** [cmTC_e3f61/fast] Error 2
```

I have xcode command line tools installed. What should I do?

Comment: Erase `cmake-build-...` directory manually and reload CMake and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase cmake-build-... directory manually and reload a CMake project.